# Custom Json data from Facebook Applinks

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I am using below piece of code for getting target_url to my App.. every thing works fine but I want to pass json data from the target site to my app.. I have refered to Applinks.org documentation but there is no precise documentation on what i want.

```
    <head>
        <meta property="al:android:url" content="example://applinks" />
        <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.example" />
        <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Example App" />
        <!-- Other headers -->
    </head>
```

On using below piece of code in my SplashActivity it throws NullPointer exception on bundle.getString("al_applink_data")..Am i refering to wrong bundle or my key/pair is wrong ???

```
        Bundle bundle=AppLinks.getAppLinkData(getIntent());
        Log.d("json i want",""+targetUrl+bundle.getString("al_applink_data"));
```

Please help!!!!

Comment: Please edit the question and add more information: Where is the `NullPointerException` thrown? Please do some debugging and establish which reference is `null`.

Comment: yes .. I have edited the question where i get null pointer exception but is my key / pair right ... please help .. I have studied https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks  that tells me to encode url.... could u please help me by giving an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bundle` that is returned by the `AppLinks.getAppLinkData(Intent)` call already contains the contents of the `"al_applink_data"` data.

Hence, you don't need to fetch the data under the `"al_applink_data"` key by calling `.getString("al_applink_data")` on that bundle. Instead, you can directly fetch the information that is nested *inside* the `"al_applink_data"` section of the data.

For a complete example, check out the AppLinks/Bolts [docs page on github](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-Android#handling-an-app-link):

```
Bundle applinkData = AppLinks.getAppLinkData(getIntent());
String id = applinkData.getString("id");
```